# Angular2: Add decorators to inherited decorators in a child class

Tags: angular, inheritance, decorator, angular-decorator, angular2-inputs

I have the following code in my Angular2 project:

```
@Component({selector: 'foo'})
export class Foo {
    @Input() protected field:any;
}

@Component({selector: 'bar'})
export class Bar extends Foo {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.field) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

In this case all work like a charm: `field` is successfully set in the Component "Bar".

But if I try to add one or more `Input` to the child Component it doesn't work. Here is the new code:

```
@Component({selector: 'foo'})
export class Foo {
    @Input() protected field:any;
}

@Component({selector: 'bar'})
export class Bar extends Foo {
    @Input() private anotherField:any;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.field) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I get the following error:

**Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'field' since it isn't a known property of 'bar'.**

It seems that setting the new Decorator variable (`anotherField`) hides the inherited Decorator variables. Am I right?

So, how to add one or more Decorator variables to a class that extends a class that has its own Decorators?

EDIT: I'm currently using Angular 2.4.2.

Comment: What version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using versione 2.4.2

Comment: Where do you bind to `field`?

Comment: In the template file: `<bar [field]="parentField" [anotherField]="anotherParentField"></bar>`

Comment: Template file of what component?

Comment: In the template of another Component in which I want to use "bar" component.

Comment: As a side note, I don't think inheriting from a decorated class is supported, or is it? More specifically, the child doesn't inherit the metadata (what's inside the decorator) from its parent class. But maybe this is not relevant in your case.

Comment: @AngularFrance I'm afraind you are wrong: Child components inherit what is inside the decorators...

Comment: Alright. Didn't try it myself. But was under that impression after reading this: https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7

Comment: That Medium article is more than one year old!

Comment: @smartmouse That's why I asked about your version, because this should be working since `2.3.0`. See [https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f5c8e09](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f5c8e09). I just tested your example code on `4.0.0-beta.7` and I get no error

Comment: @PierreDuc I solved, I had a old version of Angular (2.1.1). Now I upgraded it to 2.4.2 and all works with no errors. Thank you!